# How can I embed a form (scaffold) into a home page using ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, scaffolding

I have created a scaffold called TRADER and gave it the entries

fname:string
lname:string
twitteruser:string
email:string

I want the form visible on the index page for the app user to submit their entry. Upon submission, I want a pop up box to appear saying " Thank you for your submission."
I do not want to show the user what they just submitted, and the DB that holds all the submissions is accessed with authentication only available to me.

**Currently** the blank form is located in localhost:3000/traders/new

**then** after submission, the app displays the submitted information.

First, How can I embed  the form into the index page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Embedding your form**

In your `index.html.erb`, add the following line:

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

Assuming that the form partial is stored under `app/view/trader` with a name `_form.html.erb`.

**Redirect**

In your `traders_controller.rb`, edit the create action so that the user is not redirected to what the entry they submitted. I assume that there is a line like `redirect_to @trader` upon a successful save on the database. Instead, use something like `redirect_to root_path`, or wherever you want the users redirected to.

**Pop-up box**

In your `traders.js.coffee` under `app/assets/javascripts`, add some codes to display alert box on a successful submission of the form. Something like:

```
$("#your_form").submit(function(event) {
  alert("Thank you for your submission.");
});
```

Comment: <%= form_for @softrun, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

Comment: Im getting this argument "First argument in the form cannot contain nil or empty" . The form works when I run it in traders/new, but when i render it in index.html, the app gets an argument. the line of code that the argument points to is above this comment

Comment: @ElMerroPero make sure you set the instance variable in the controller